# How to have access to the inputs of the composite githb action in script files called from the composite action

Tags: bash, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to store the scripts of my composite github actions in the directory of action and then use the inputs of the composite action inside the script.
let me explain with an example

- Suppose I am in the myorg organization
- I create a repository named actions
- I create a directory named `mydemo`
- I create a file `mydemo/action.yaml`
- I create another file `mydemo/echo.sh`

In `mydemo/action.yaml` It works if I have

```
name: "mydemo"
description: ""
inputs:
  name:
    description: ""

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: echo hello world
      run: |
        echo ${{ inputs.name }}
      shell: bash
```

It also works if I do

```
name: "mydemo"
description: ""
inputs:
  name:
    description: ""

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: echo hello world
      run: |
        source ${GITHUB_ACTION_PATH}/echo.sh
      shell: bash
```

and then in `mydemo/echo.sh` I write `echo "Hello World"`

But it does not work if in `mydemo/echo.sh` I write `echo ${{ inputs.name }}`

How can I have access to `${{ inputs.name }}` inside  `mydemo/echo.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `inputs` as env vars using `env` and then access those inside the script.

See [`runs.steps[*].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsenv).

Example (only relevant parts):

`script.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "$NAME"
```

`action.yml`

```yaml
# ...

runs:
  using: 'composite'

  steps:
  - name: Test
    env:
      NAME: '${{ inputs.name }}'
    shell: bash
    run: $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/script.sh
```